# How to add createMaterialTopTabNavigator inside createBottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

[image]

i want to do something like this top tabs should come inside bottom home tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that when you press the 'Home' button in the bottomNav the topNav appears?

Then you can just do the following(with login);

```
const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  loginFlow: createStackNavigator({
    Signup: SignupScreen,
    Signin: SigninScreen
  }),
  mainFlow: createBottomTabNavigator({
    bottomFlow: createStackNavigator({
      Home: HomeScreen,
      Settings: SettingsScreen
    }),
    topFlow: createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
      topScreen1: TopScreen1,
      topScreen2: TopScreen2,
      topScreen3: TopScreen3
    })
  });

  export default createAppContainer(switchNavigator);
```

When you import everything, I think this should do it.

Comment: yeah something like that